# I want to see (inside chrome console) what inside this jQuery "text()" method body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, methods, get

```
 $(selector).click(function(){
 alert("Text: " + $(selector).text());
 });
```

how can i see what inside this "text()" method ?I want to console the text() function body. I want to know how this method work.

Comment: Look at jquery source on github

Comment: be sure you are selecting the exactly element you targeting with the right way and if u want view the result in web console, open it with key F12 and you can check the console.

Comment: console.log("Text: " + $(selector).text()); You can check result in web console.